# How to enqueue and dequeue a lot at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, queue, thread-safety, nonblocking

I have a simple scenario with two threads where the first thread reads permanently some data and enqueues that data into a queue. The second thread first peeks at a single object from that queue and makes some conditional checks. If these are good the single object will be dequeued and passed to some processing.

I have tried to use the `ConcurrentQueue` which is a thread safe implementation of a simple queue, but the problem with this one is that all calls are blocking. This means if the first thread is enqueuing an object, the second thread can't peek or dequeue an object.

In my situation I need to enqueue at the end and dequeue from the beginning of the queue at the same time.

The lock statement of C# would also.

So my question is whether it is possible to do these both operations in parallel without blocking each other in a thread safe way.

These are my first tries and this is an similar example for my problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Scenario {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Scenario scenario = new Scenario();
            scenario.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class Scenario {
            public Scenario() {
                someData = new Queue<int>();
            }

            public void Start() {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(firstThread);
                Task.Factory.StartNew(secondThread);
            }

            private void firstThread() {
                Random random = new Random();
                while (true) {
                    int newData = random.Next(1, 100);
                    someData.Enqueue(newData);
                    Console.WriteLine("Enqueued " + newData);
                }
            }

            private void secondThread() {
                Random random = new Random();
                while (true) {
                    if (someData.Count == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    int singleData = someData.Peek();

                    int someValue = random.Next(1, 100);
                    if (singleData > someValue || singleData == 1 || singleData == 99) {
                        singleData = someData.Dequeue();
                        Console.WriteLine("Dequeued " + singleData);
                        // ... processing ...
                    }
                }
            }

            private readonly Queue<int> someData;
        }
    }
}
```

Second example:

```
public class Scenario {
    public Scenario() {
        someData = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
    }

    public void Start() {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(firstThread);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(secondThread);
    }

    private void firstThread() {
        Random random = new Random();
        while (true) {
            int newData = random.Next(1, 100);
            someData.Enqueue(newData);
            lock (syncRoot) { Console.WriteLine($"Enqued {enqued++} Dequed {dequed}"); }
        }
    }

    private void secondThread() {
        Random random = new Random();
        while (true) {
            if (!someData.TryPeek(out int singleData)) {
                continue;
            }

            int someValue = random.Next(1, 100);
            if (singleData > someValue || singleData == 1 || singleData == 99) {
                if (!someData.TryDequeue(out singleData)) {
                    continue;
                }

                lock (syncRoot) { Console.WriteLine($"Enqued {enqued} Dequed {dequed++}"); }

                // ... processing ...
            }
        }
    }

    private int enqued = 0;
    private int dequed = 0;

    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<int> someData;

    private static readonly object syncRoot = new object();
}
```

Comment: You can use the third thread for doing all the work with the queue and the 2  other threads talk to the third thread and they do not directly work with the queue

Comment: @EhsanZargarErshadi Other than consuming a bunch more system resources for an extra thread that isn't doing anything productive, that hasn't gotten you anything.

Comment: Why is it important to you to be both adding and removing concurrently?  Typically the processing needed to produce or consume the value is *dramatically* more expensive than the time it takes to actually add or remove an item from the queue, so lock contention tends to be low.  What problems were you actually having in practice that made simply synchronizing access to the queue unacceptable?

Comment: You should certainly be using the ConcurrentQueue class and it's TryXxxx methods for this.

Comment: My actual problem is that i have a machine setup with a line triangulation sensor, an axis and an code base which was built that way.
The sensor produces 100 samples every step it moves on an axis.
By a fast movement i can archive 1000 measured points per second and more.
These points are all enqued into the queue.
The real problem is that i cant dequeue and process a lot of points because i am permanently reading and enquing new points.
That enqueue calls are blocking the processing step.

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem enqueueing and dequeuing 1000 items per second when synchronizing access to a queue.  If you are, you have a problem with how you implemented it, not the inherent approach.  Now if you were adding *billions* (or honestly, probably just millions) of items per second, then maybe you'd need to look at making some changes to avoid lock contention.

Comment: @Servy I disagree. I have rewritten my example with a concurrent queue and some counters and the dequing stops at a certain number like 260 times. After that only enquing is happening. Edited post.

Comment: @StudentBanana You've also synchronized the entirety of the processing.  That means that between the two there isn't any work that can actually be done in parallel.  If you actually did the processing of the items in parallel you wouldn't have problems synchronizing access to the queue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off: I *strongly* encourage you to reconsider whether your technique of having multiple threads and a shared memory data structure is even the right approach at all. Code that has multiple threads of control sharing access to data structures is hard to get right, and failures can be subtle, catastrophic, and hard to debug.

Second: If you are bent upon multiple threads and a shared memory data structure, I *strongly* encourage you to use designed-by-experts data types like concurrent queues, rather than rolling your own.

Now that I've got those warnings out of the way: here is a way to address your concern. It is sufficiently complicated that you should obtain the services of an expert on the C# memory model to verify the correctness of your solution if you go with this. I would not consider myself to be competent to implement the scheme I'm about to describe, not without help of someone who is actually an expert on the memory model.

The goal is to have a queue that supports simultaneous enqueue and dequeue operations and low lock contention.

What you want is **two immutable stack variables** called the **enqueue** stack and the **dequeue** stack, each with their own lock.

The enqueue operation is:

- Take the enqueue lock
- Push the item onto the enqueue stack; this produces a new stack in O(1) time.
- Assign the newly produced stack to the enqueue stack variable.
- Release the enqueue lock

The dequeue operation is:

- Take the dequeue lock
- If the dequeue stack is empty then
- - take the enqueue lock
- - enumerate the enqueue stack and use it to build the dequeue stack; this *reverses* the enqueue stack, which maintains the property we want: that the first in is the first out.
- - assign an empty immutable stack to the enqueue stack variable
- - release the enqueue lock
- - assign the new stack to the dequeue stack
- If the dequeue stack is empty, throw, or abandon and retry later, or sleep until signaled by the enqueue operation, or whatever the right thing to do here is.
- The dequeue stack is not empty.
- Pop an item from the dequeue stack, which produces a new stack in O(1).
- Assign the new stack to the dequeue stack variable.
- Release the dequeue lock.
- Process the item.

Note that of course if there is only one thread dequeuing, then we don't need the dequeue lock at all, but with this scheme there can be many threads dequeuing.

Suppose there are 1000 items on the enqueue stack and zero on the dequeue stack.  When we dequeue the first time, we do an expensive O(n) operation of reversing the enqueue stack *once*, but now we have 1000 items on the dequeue stack.  Once the dequeue stack is big, the dequeueing thread can spend most of its time processing, while the enqueuing thread spends most of its time enqueuing. Contention on the enqueue lock is *rare*, but *expensive when it happens*.

Why use immutable data structures? Everything I described here would also work with mutable stacks, but (1) it is easier to reason about immutable stacks, (2) if you want to really live dangerously you can elide some of the locks and go for interlocked swap operations; make sure you understand *everything* about the possible re-orderings of operations in low-lock conditions if you're doing that.

UPDATE:

> The real problem is that i cant dequeue and process a lot of points because i am permanently reading and enquing new points. That enqueue calls are blocking the processing step.

Well if that is your real problem then **mentioning it in the question** instead of burying it in a comment would be a good idea. Help us help you.

There are a number of things you could do here. You could for example set the priority of the enqueuing thread lower than the priority of the dequeuing thread.  Or you could have multiple dequeuing threads, as many as there are CPUs in your machine.  Or you could dynamically choose to drop some enqueue operations if the dequeues are not keeping up.  Without knowing a lot more about your actual problem it is hard to give advice on how to solve it.

Comment: Nice answer. Wouldn't it be better to use two immutable queues, instead of two immutable stacks? That way the movement from the writing queue to the reading queue can be performed in O(1) worst case.

Comment: @Fede: That's a nice thought, though if it is a *persistent* immutable queue then *it is probably implemented as two immutable stacks*, and so all you've done is move the problem around. My intention in describing the mechanism like this was to give some insights into the fact that *there is almost always an expensive operation in there somewhere*; mutable queues use double-when-full algorithms, for instance, which also incur an occasional O(n) step that is amortized over O(n) cheap steps.

Comment: Normally we think of expensive steps as disadvantages, but in cases like these we can use them to advantage because we turn many frequent little contention slowdowns into infrequent big slowdowns, and that is often a net win.